Prove the intersection number of a irreducible curve and its hessian at a simple node is 6
I am trying to solve problem 7.22 in Fulton's Algebraic Curves. In the first part of the question, we are asked to prove the intersection of an irreducible plane curve $F$ and its hessian $H$ is 6 at a simple node $P$. By simple node, we mean $P$ is a node (an ordinary double point) and $I(P, L_i \cap F) = 3$ for each of the tangent lines $L_i, i = 1, 2$ of $F$ at $P$.
To simplify the matters, we may assume $P = [0:0:1]$ and the tangent lines are $X, Y$, then $F = XY + \text{higher terms}$.
The problem then hints that we can use Proposition 2 in Section 7.5 to prove that the terms of degree $\ge 4$ in $F$ may be ignored. This is where I am confused. Proposition 2 in Section 7.5 basically says $I(P, C \cap G) = \sum_{f(Q) = P} ord_{Q}(g)$ where $f: X \rightarrow C$ is a birational morphism from a nonsingular projective curve onto $G$, and $ord_Q(g)$ is the order of $G$ regarded as an element in $k(X) = k(C)$.
I was wondering how to apply this proposition to the problem. Since the process of obtaining $f, X$ from $C$ is quite complicated(it involves quadratic transformations and blowing up points), I do not know how to compute $ord_{Q}(g)$. Then how is proposition 2 helpful?

Actually, in your case, it's not so bad - if $P$ is the node, then the map $f:X\to C$ is a 2-1 map over $P$ which takes the two preimages $Q_1,Q_2$ of the node and smushes them together. This gives that $I(P,C\cap G) = ord_{Q_1}(g) + ord_{Q_2}(g)$.
Now we take $G$ to be the curve cut out by the Hessian. From exercise 5.23, we can find that the Hessian in local coordinates is of the form $f_y^2f_{xx}+f_x^2f_{yy}-2f_xf_yf_{xy}$. Let's calculate, where we write $f=xy+a+b$ for $a=a_0x^3+a_1x^2y+a_2xy^2+a_3y^3$ homogeneous of degree 3 and $b$ is all the terms of degree 4 and higher. Taking partial derivatives and expanding, $$g=(x+a_y+b_y)^2(a_{xx}+b_{xx}) + (y+a_x+b_x)^2(a_{yy}+b_{yy}) - 2(x+a_y+b_y)(y+a_x+b_x)(1+a_{xy}+b_{xy}),$$ and picking out the degree 2 and 3 terms, we see that we have $$g=(-2xy)+(x^2a_{xx}+y^2a_{yy}-2xya_{xy}-2xa_x-2ya_y))+\cdots,$$ which after applying Euler's theorem on homogeneous polynomials and doing a bunch of algebra can be simplified to $$g=-2(xy+4a_1x^2y+4a_2xy^2)+\cdots,$$ where $\cdots$ is things of degree 4 and higher. Applying the property that $I(P,V(r)\cap V(s))=I(P,V(r)\cap V(r+cs))$ for any $c$, we can replace $g$ by $g+2f=2(a_0x^3+3a_1x^2y+3a_2xy^2+a_3y^3)+\cdots$. By the assumption that $P$ is a simple node, we have $a_0,a_3\neq 0$, so $g+2f$ has a nonzero component of degree 3 and after maybe a little more argument you can conclude that in fact the order of $g+2f$ at each of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ is exactly 3.
